# Logs file is empty in spring boot application docker container

Tags: linux, spring-boot, docker, logging

I have a spring-boot application running inside a docker container & its working fine. But the thing is application log file is empty inside the docker container.
In logback-spring.xml log path has been configured to /var/log.
When I go to /var/log directory inside the docker container, I can see log file has been created like "myservice.log"
but when I "cat" the file to see the content, that is completely empty.
Also when I execute

```
docker logs <container-id>
```

it returns nothing.

And also I checked the docker root directory in the server.

```
/apps/docker/containers/<container-id>/<container-id-json.log>
```

that is also empty.

my Dockerfile has the following structure.

```
From private-docker-repo/openjdk:11-jre-slim

WORKDIR /opt/services

COPY target/my-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/services/my-service.jar

CMD java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dserver.port=61016 -jar my-service.jar

EXPOSE 61016
```

What can be the reason for being the log file is empty here. Highly appreciate if anyone can point me out.

Edit - when I deploy the same jar using a linux systemd service logs are just writing fine. I want to know why the same jar not printing any logs inside the docker container

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Why you think there sould be output in the logs?

Comment: Log are writting just fine when I deploy the jar using a linux systemd service. @Jens

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your application running? Get into the docker container and check whether it's running, seems to me it's not started.

Comment: yes It is running and functional

Comment: As per the solution you have used, there is no big difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT other that CMD is accepted command line argument. I think the issue is, the way you used CMD or ENTRYPOINT, you must required to use CMD or ENTRYPOINT as a exec versions rather than shell versions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this just by replacing the `CMD` command with `ENTRYPOINT`. Now the logs are printing just fine. I did some search on the difference between `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` but still I cant understand how that affect the logging of a container. So if anyone can add a comment what could be happened, that's great not only for me but for the other who will see this question in future.

Thank you :)